# Type with bad antialiasing using webkit transformation, what's the cause?

Tags: css, types, safari

I'm using a script that uses Webkit transformations, and in Safari I can see the type jagged, not clear — like in an old pc browser.

The type is good in Chrome and Safari Mobile. What could it be? Do I have to set anything on CSS?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is... but, you can always force antialisasing with this:

```
html
{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

the 'text-rendering' function is optional, it only affects Windows and Linux.
[Learn more »](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-rendering)